# "Unable to install" Error in TestFlight with iOS 8?

Tags: ios, ios8, testflight

I am trying to distribute a test flight build to external users, I have followed apples steps, uploaded the build, submitted for beta review, etc. but now when I attempt to install the build on external devices I'm getting an unable to install error message. The same message one would receive if it was not provisioned properly.

The app is provisioned for distribution, but I thought that was the whole point of the test flight external testers and I misunderstanding something ?

Comment: Did it pass the review process? Are you installing it through the TestFlight app (available on the AppStore)?

Comment: Yes- It was reviewed and approved, and I'm using the test flight app from the app store to install the app. I can see my app inside the test flight application, I have access to it and it is valid. But when I click install it gets ~90% of the way, and then fails out with the error "unable to install"

Comment: Hmm... that does sound like a signing issue. But then... the test wouldn't pass if they weren't able to install it.